# Assembly language Array traversal

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly language and I'm having trouble with some basic programming problems and I was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction. 
I'm trying to write a function that traverses through an array and sums up the values of its elements. Given given a pointer int *array and some length x.

What I've been able to do so far is write the initial data and place the initial pointer which isn't much but its a start. How would I use a loop in assembly to traverse through the array?

`PUSH EBX`
  `PUSH ECX` 
  `PUSH EDX` 
  `PUSH ESI` 
  `PUSH EDI`

`MOV EBX, array` 
  `MOV ECX, x`

`mov eax, 2;` 
  `mov ebx, array;` 
  `lea edx, [ebx+eax*4];`

Comment: Did you consider compiling a very simple C program and see how the compiler does it? `gcc -S mycode.c` will produce `mycode.s`... If that doesn't help, good info at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_loops.htm

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to save all of those registers.  If your function uses `esi`, `edi`, `ebx`, `ebp`, then you must save them in the prologue and restore them in the epilogue.  MASM can do that for you with the keyword `uses`

```
SomeProcedure proc uses esi, edi, ebx Val1:DWORD, Val2:DWORD

    ret
SomeProcedure endp
```

Here is one way you can do it:

```
.686                                     
.model flat, stdcall     
option casemap :none   

include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
Array   dd  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
Array_Size  equ ($ - Array) / 4

.code
start:

    push    Array_Size - 1
    push    offset Array
    call    SumArray
    ; eax contains sum of array
    ; print it out here.

    push    0
    call    ExitProcess

SumArray:    
    push    esi             ; need to preserve esi

    mov     esi, [esp + 8]  ; address of array
    mov     ecx, [esp + 12] ; size of array - 1
    xor     eax, eax        ; holds sum
    xor     edx, edx        ; index

AddIt:
    add     eax, [esi + edx * 4]     
    inc     edx
    dec     ecx
    jns     AddIt           ; is ecx ! neg repeat loop

    pop     esi
    ret
end start
```